# Deploy Node.js React apps to Heroku - stuck on build indefinitely

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku

I have an amazing Camping Application- but have trouble deploying it to Heroku. Running on WSL Ubuntu.

When I run git add . git commit -am "make it better" git push heroku main the build just hangs and doesn't move forward. Any ideas why this is happening? I'm using node.js and react and the app runs find locally.

```
Git add .
Git commit -am "Deploy to Heroku"
Git push heroku main
```

Also tried git push heroku master.

Any ideas why this is happening?

```
Activity Feed  Build LogID 6149d7d8-7f74-43a8-be32-cd8a78135a0d
-----> Building on the Heroku-22 stack
-----> Determining which buildpack to use for this app
-----> Node.js app detected
       
-----> Creating runtime environment
       
       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NODE_VERBOSE=false
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
       
-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  14.0.0
       engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
       
       Resolving node version 14.0.0...
       Downloading and installing node 14.0.0...
       Using default npm version: 6.14.4
       
-----> Installing dependencies
       Installing node modules
       
       > @fortawesome/fontawesome-free@6.3.0 postinstall /tmp/build_6521a66b/node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free
       > node attribution.js
       
       Font Awesome Free 6.3.0 by @fontawesome - https://fontawesome.com
       License - https://fontawesome.com/license/free (Icons: CC BY 4.0, Fonts: SIL OFL 1.1, Code: MIT License)
       Copyright 2023 Fonticons, Inc.
       
       
       > fsevents@1.2.13 install /tmp/build_6521a66b/node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents
       > node install.js
       
       
       Skipping 'fsevents' build as platform linux is not supported
       
       > core-js@2.6.12 postinstall /tmp/build_6521a66b/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js
       > node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"
       
       
       > ejs@2.7.4 postinstall /tmp/build_6521a66b/node_modules/ejs
       > node ./postinstall.js
       
       
       > es5-ext@0.10.62 postinstall /tmp/build_6521a66b/node_modules/es5-ext
       >  node -e "try{require('./_postinstall')}catch(e){}" || exit 0
       
       
       > core-js@3.27.2 postinstall /tmp/build_6521a66b/node_modules/core-js
       > node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"
       
       
       > bcrypt@5.1.0 install /tmp/build_6521a66b/node_modules/bcrypt
       > node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
       
       [bcrypt] Success: "/tmp/build_6521a66b/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/napi-v3/bcrypt_lib.node" is installed via remote
       added 2112 packages in 17.319s
       
-----> Build
       Running build
       
       > snappycamper@0.1.0 build /tmp/build_6521a66b
       > concurrently "npm run start-fe" "npm run start-be"
       
       [0] 
       [0] > snappycamper@0.1.0 start-fe /tmp/build_6521a66b
       [0] > react-scripts start
       [0] 
       [1] 
       [1] > snappycamper@0.1.0 start-be /tmp/build_6521a66b
       [1] > node ./backend/server.js
       [1] 
       [1] SnappyCamper Config:
       [1] SECRET_KEY: secret-dev
       [1] PORT: 3001
       [1] BCRYPT_WORK_FACTOR 12
       [1] Database: postgres://anwobktcvezqqp:dbc11b5e99516fc6dfb2ac6b7c0fe9e0f5ce5a8109bdc80bad4942740f501d3f@ec2-54-173-77-184.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/d3rs57gm06h7un
       [1] ---
       [1] postgres://anwobktcvezqqp:dbc11b5e99516fc6dfb2ac6b7c0fe9e0f5ce5a8109bdc80bad4942740f501d3f@ec2-54-173-77-184.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/d3rs57gm06h7un
       [1] Started on postgres://anwobktcvezqqp:dbc11b5e99516fc6dfb2ac6b7c0fe9e0f5ce5a8109bdc80bad4942740f501d3f@ec2-54-173-77-184.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/d3rs57gm06h7un
       [0] :information_source: ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://172.16.80.46/
       [0] :information_source: ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from 
       [0] :information_source: ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /tmp/build_6521a66b/public
       [0] :information_source: ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /
       [0] Starting the development server...
       [0] 
       [0] Compiled with warnings.
       [0] 
       [0] src/App.js
       [0]   Line 72:9:  'getUser' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars
       [0] 
       [0] src/Routes/CampList.js
       [0]   Line 15:3:    'MDBBtn' is defined but never used                no-unused-vars
       [0]   Line 22:10:   'limitNumber' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars
       [0]   Line 70:18:   'name' is assigned a value but never used         no-unused-vars
       [0]   Line 113:33:  Unexpected string concatenation of literals       no-useless-concat
       [0] 
       [0] src/Routes/ProfileForm.js
       [0]   Line 8:24:  'updateUser' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars
       [0] 
       [0] Search for the keywords to learn more about each warning.
       [0] To ignore, add // eslint-disable-next-line to the line before.
       [0] 
-----> Timed out running buildpack Node.js

{
  "name": "snappycamper",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.2",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^6.2.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "axios": "^1.2.1",
    "babel-jest": "^29.4.2",
    "bcrypt": "^5.1.0",
    "colors": "^1.4.0",
    "concurrently": "^7.6.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "jest": "^26.6.0",
    "jsonschema": "^1.4.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.0",
    "mdb-react-ui-kit": "^5.1.0",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "node-polyfill-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.1",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "pg": "^8.8.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.0",
    "react-scripts": "^4.0.3",
    "reactstrap": "^9.1.5",
    "supertest": "^6.3.3",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4",
    "webpack": "^4.44.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "concurrently \"npm run start-fe\" \"npm run start-be\"",
    "build": "concurrently \"npm run start-fe\" \"npm run start-be\"",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "start-fe": "react-scripts start",
    "start-be": "node ./backend/server.js"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "react-scripts/eslint-webpack-plugin": "^2.3.0",
    "react-scripts-overlay": "^6.0.9"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "14.0.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.

Comment: I strongly suggest you never actually use "make it better" as a commit message. Take a moment to think of a good, concise description for the change you are committing.

Comment: @Chris Thank you'll edit this with proper code and include my error logs. Also I'll choose a more accurate message in commit.